# How to make flutter TextField at bottom of screen show over IME

Tags: flutter

My page is a SingleChildScrollView,it's has a column as child .And I have a TextField at bottom of the screen.
How can I make the TextField show over of IME when IME is expend.
now the TextField is covered by IME. And it is invisible,util scroll manually.

demo code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          elevation: 0.0,
          title: new Text(
            'title',
          ),
        ),
        body: new Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SingleChildScrollView(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new ImageZone(),
          new Div(),
          new TextEditZone(),
          new Div(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ImageZone extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new ImageZoneState();
}

class ImageZoneState extends State<ImageZone> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      elevation: 1.0,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: new Container(
        height: 380.0,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: new Icon(
          Icons.access_time,
          size: 360.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Div extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SizedBox(
      height: 12.0,
    );
  }
}

class TextEditZone extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new TextEditZoneState();
  }
}

class TextEditZoneState extends State<TextEditZone> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      elevation: 1.0,
      child: new Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.white,
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            new TextField(
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
              textAlign: TextAlign.end,
            ),
            new Div(),
            new TextField(
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
              textAlign: TextAlign.end,
            ),
            new Div(),
            new TextField(
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
              textAlign: TextAlign.end,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

screen Shot:

[image]
[image]

What I want:
TextField auto scroll over IME when I click one of TextField.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was solved in this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172962/how-to-limit-scroll-distance-in-a-scroll-view-in-flutter)
, Please go through and wrap all your `TextField` 's inside `EnsureVisibleWhenFocused` and this will bring the `TextField` just above the keyboard.

Regards,
Mahi

Comment: I copy the sample code and run on emulator,it seems not work at all. All code is here: https://gist.github.com/Qixingchen/ee1592e08ea4fcf4957da6d6e8742267 dose it need some pre-config?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sGWC2nukw1ljmo6LdDVf7NLqtIQBnnj9/view?usp=sharing screen record is here